# AWS S3 CLI - how to get JSON with all current policies set on a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I am testing S3 commands from EC2.

How to list all policies currently set for a specific bucket? (in AWS Web Console - I can see that json but want to do that trough AWS CLI)

Also - how to create S3 bucket trough CLI (from EC2) and attach all the policies via JSON (or by adding configuration commands)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one S3 policy per bucket. This command will display this policy:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket
```

This command will create a bucket:

```
aws s3 mb s3://mybucket --region us-west-1
```

This command will create attach a policy to a bucket:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --policy file://policy.json
```

[S3 get-bucket-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-policy.html)

[S3 make bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mb.html)

[Example Bucket Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)